# Python - Easiest way to get ordered key/value pairs from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary, age_freq:

```
age_freq = {'Age35-44': 194, 'Age0-14': 11, 'Age55-64': 51, 'Age45-54': 142, 'Age65-74': 12, 'Age15-24': 223, 'Age25-34': 310}
```

I want to return the key/value pairs from this dictionary for the purposes of creating a pie chart.  My code to do this is below:

```
age_range=[]
freq=[]

for key, value in age_freq.iteritems():
    aKey = key
    aValue = value
    age_range.append(aKey)
    freq.append(aValue)
```

This works fine and I get the following two lists:

```
age_range = ['Age35-44', 'Age0-14', 'Age65-74', 'Age45-54', 'Age55-64', 'Age15-24', 'Age25-34']

freq = [194, 11, 12, 142, 51, 223, 310]
```

However I want the lists to be ordered by increasing age range. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort it.

```
age_range, freq = zip(*sorted(age_freq.items()))
```

If the age ranges were less tidy, as mentioned in comments, you could explicitly extract them, with (for example) turning the low and high end of each range into an integer and then finding their average:

```
age_range, freq = zip(*sorted(age_freq.items(), key=lambda x: (int(x[3].split('-')[0]) + int(x[3].split('-')[1]) / 2))
```

Comment: You combined `age_range` and `freq` into `age_freq`. Is that allowed?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you mean the argument unpacking?

Comment: This only happens to work because the age ranges are all using two digits. Now add `Age5-15` in there.. You may want to be more careful and extract the first of the two ages and convert it to an integer.

Comment: Yes... the `(age_freq.items()))` part

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yes, if the input data were different, it would require different code. This could include an age range that starts with a single digit, overlapping age ranges, and so on. For now, however, this level of complexity works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most pythonic way to do this would be:

```
sortedFreq = [(key, age_freq[key]) for key in sorted(age_freq)]
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to call `keys()` when sorting a dictionary. `sorted(age_freq)` gives the same output without creating an intermediary list.

Comment: Your correct that `keys()` is not needed. However - in Python 3 - it does not create an intermediary list; it's a generator.

Comment: It still creates an intermediary object that isn't needed. And it is not a generator that `dict.keys()` returs, it is a dictionary view (a set-like object).

Comment: Fair enough; it's still not a list.

Comment: Note that the OP used `dict.iteritems()` so we can guess they use Python 2. And calling methods where you don't need to is always best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's very tidy and efficient but I think sometimes readability/reusability counts so I suggest converting it to a list of dictionaries:

```
age_freq = {'Age35-44': 194, 'Age0-14': 11, 'Age55-64': 51, 'Age45-54': 142, 'Age65-74': 12, 'Age15-24': 223, 'Age25-34': 310}

table = [{'start': int(key.split('Age')[1].split('-')[0]),
          'stop': int(key.split('Age')[1].split('-')[1]),
          'freq': age_freq[key]}
         for key in age_freq]
```

and now you can do whatever you like with it: Sort by start-age

```
import operator
sorted(table, key=operator.itemgetter('start'))
```

Sort by stop-age

```
sorted(table, key=operator.itemgetter('start'))
```

Sort by frequency

```
sorted(table, key=operator.itemgetter('freq'))
```

but thats probably not the "easiest" way.

Answer (score -1):

Python's dictionaries are not ordered, so iteritems() will return the keys and values in the same 'order' as before

To create ordered key/value lists you can do something like this:

```
for key in sorted(age_freq.keys()):
    aKey = key
    aValue = age_freq.pop(key)

    age_range.append(aKey)
    freq.append(aValue)
```

Since this pops the keys out one by one at the end you'll be left with an empty dictionary, but if you're just creating a pie chart it shouldn't matter.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to call `keys()` when sorting a dictionary. `sorted(age_freq)` gives the same output without creating an intermediary list.

Comment: Also, why destroy the original dictionary by popping off the values?